# MySQL 'cant reopen (temporary) table)

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Attempting to normalize a column (`wgt`) by joining to the result of an inline query as follows:

```
select a.monthEnd, ticker, wgt/totWgt 
from hold a
inner join ( 
            select monthEnd, sum(wgt*(1+totRet)) as totWgt
            from hold
            group by monthEnd ) tot
            on a.monthEnd = tot.monthEnd
```

Get the following error:

`Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 'a'  0.00023 sec`

I'm coming from SQL Server and not acquainted.  What exactly is the issue and/or workaround here?  Both tables referenced are temporary tables created within a stored proc and running MySQL 8.0.

Comment: It looks like you cannot refer the temporary table more than once in the same query , please use WITH clause

Answer (score 0):

Please use **WITH** clause,

```
WITH hold as 
(SELECT monthEnd, wgt, totWgt , totRet, ticker FROM <actual table>)
select a.monthEnd, ticker, wgt/totWgt 
from hold a inner join 
(select monthEnd, sum(wgt*(1+totRet)) as totWgt from hold group by monthEnd ) tot
on a.monthEnd = tot.monthEnd;
```

Comment: Instead of creating `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE hold select * from TABLE;` please use `WITH hold as (SELECT monthEnd, ticker, wgt, totWgt from TABLE)` and use the reference in the subsequent places. EDITED the answer accordingly